# Serialization problem in a custom collection with a private list

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, jsonconvert

Given two classes as follows:

```
class ListCollection : List<int>
{
}

[Serializable]
class PrivateListCollection: ISerializable
{
    private List<int> list = new List<int>();

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        list.Add(value);
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("items", list);
    }
}
```

I get after adding 1,2,3 to each of them and serializing using JsonConvert.SerializeObject this:

```
ListCollection: [1,2,3]
PrivateListCollection: {"items":[1,2,3]}
```

The question is whether it's possible to get the serialization result of PrivateListCollection as [1,2,3] (without the "items" or whatever in front of it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An POCO cannot serialize itself as a JSON array by implementing [`ISerializable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable) because a JSON array is an ordered sequence of values, while [`SerializationInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo) represents a collection of name/value pairs -- which matches exactly the definition of a JSON object rather than an array.  This is confirmed by the [Json.NET docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#ISerializable):

> **ISerializable**
>
> Types that implement [ISerializable](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wf4375ks) and are marked with [SerializableAttribute](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcfsa90a) are serialized as **JSON objects**. When serializing, only the values returned from ISerializable.GetObjectData are used; members on the type are ignored. When deserializing, the constructor with a SerializationInfo and StreamingContext is called, passing the JSON object's values.

To serialize your `PrivateListCollection` as a JSON array, you have a couple of options.

**Firstly**, you could create a [custom `JsonConverer`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm):

```
class PrivateListCollectionConverter : JsonConverter<PrivateListCollection>
{
    const string itemsName = "items";
    
    public override PrivateListCollection ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, PrivateListCollection existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var list = serializer.Deserialize<List<int>>(reader);
        if (list == null)
            return null;
        existingValue = existingValue ?? new PrivateListCollection();
        foreach (var item in list)
            existingValue.Add(item);
        return existingValue;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, PrivateListCollection value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // There doesn't seem to be any way to extract the items from the PrivateListCollection other than to call GetObjectData(), so let's do that.
        // Adding PrivateListCollectionConverter as a nested type inside PrivateListCollection would be another option to make the items accessible.
        ISerializable serializable = value;
        var info = new SerializationInfo(value.GetType(), new FormatterConverter());
        serializable.GetObjectData(info, serializer.Context);
        var list = info.GetValue(itemsName, typeof(IEnumerable<int>));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
    }
}
```

And then either add it to `PrivateListCollection` like so:

```
[Serializable]
[JsonConverter(typeof(PrivateListCollectionConverter))]
class PrivateListCollection: ISerializable
{
    // Remainder unchanged
```

Or add it to [`JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) like so:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new PrivateListCollectionConverter() },
};
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/31eX5e).

**Secondly**, you could make `PrivateListCollection` implement `IEnumerable<int>` and add a parameterized constructor taking a single `IEnumerable<int>` parameter like so:

```
[Serializable]
class PrivateListCollection: ISerializable, IEnumerable<int>
{
    public PrivateListCollection() { }
    public PrivateListCollection(IEnumerable<int> items) => list.AddRange(items);

    private List<int> list = new List<int>();

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        list.Add(value);
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("items", list);
    }
            
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() => list.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Having done so, Json.NET will see `PrivateListCollection` as a [constructible read-only collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36927705/3744182) which can be round-tripped as a JSON array.  However, based on the fact that you have named your type **`PrivateListCollection`**, you may not want to implement enumeration.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hOxj5v).

Comment: Thanks, IEnumerable<int> did the trick. In fact, I don't even need the ISerializable or [Serializable]